# Align text to image (CSS)

Tags: css, alignment

How it is now: http://jsfiddle.net/cSazm/

How I want it to be: http://jsfiddle.net/mhprg/

The problem with the second variant is that I don't know the exact size of the image, so the fixed CSS margin would not work :(
Also there's an extra ugly div..

Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ["shrinkwrap" method](http://www.css-lab.com/lab-work/auto-width/shrink-wrap-col.html), to contain the text and prevent it from flowing below the image:

http://jsfiddle.net/cSazm/5/

(just add `overflow:hidden` to your text div)

That doesn't solve the extra div issue however.

Answer (score 4):

You can float the image, and then style the `div` as a table cell, which will automatically stretch to 100% the available width.

**HTML:**

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/80/80/" alt="" /><div>Text</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div{
    display:table-cell;
}    

img{
    float:left;
}
```

↪ [View this example at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cSazm/16/)

Comment: Should probably be using a paragraph tag instead of a div.

Comment: @cimmanon You're probably right, but since the TS used `div`s in his question I'll leave that up to him to change.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to put a width on the text (which you should put in a p tag or whatever you prefer). Then you can float the p left.

It's not ideal, and based on the bigger picture that might not work for what you want to build, but it's the best way. Especially seeing as floating left is built for making an object such as an image inline with text, so in essence you are trying to overwrite the norm which css doesn't take too kindly to!

Comment: Not the best solution if you want your layout to be fluid and you don't know the width of your image. What if your image is 600px long?

Comment: Yes, as I said based on the bigger picture it might not work depending on the site you're building. It is commonly regarded as the best solution though.

As you said in the other answer, table-cell does work but it is not best practice as that property does not work in IE7. If the site isn't meant for all browsers, then that's fine, but then why would anyone build a site that is fluid for all screen sized but then doesn't consider all browsers.

Comment: For IE7 I use Google Chrome Frame, it works greatly and saves me form a headache

Answer (score 2):

If you have your image floated (left in this case) apply `overflow:hidden;` to your text div. So your CSS should be:

```
image{
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

text-div{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Your content will never flow below the image with this technique regardless of image/text size.

To learn more about this, Nicole Sullivan wrote an awesome blog-post on it: http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/07/23/overflow-a-secret-benefit/

Answer (score 1):

Simple, set a margin-right fot the image like so:

```
img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the text flows below the image. Thelolcat wants two columns, the left one with the image and the right one with text.

Comment: Ok the you should wrap your image in another div and the text into a paragraph and set the display for both of them to table-cell, like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/cSazm/

Answer (score 1):

fix the image width like

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/80/80/"  width="42" />
```

now add the your text in a tag like div or p

```
 <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.
      </div>
```

nest above tags in a single div.
now just assign the text margin as the width of image

```
.text{
    margin-left: 42px;
}
```

as I have set the width of the image 42 above.

Comment: In the question, he stated he doesn't know the exact size of the image.

Comment: yes I know that's why I told him to add the width of the image or may get the image width by some javascript don't know now and assign that to text by script.